# Load SQL Onpremises data incrementally to Azure Blob Storage through Azure data factory

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I would like to load data from On-premisse SQL Tables  incrementally to Azure Blob Storage using Azure data factory creating folders with the data name to each table. I couldn't find any relavant documentation to do this. Appreciate if there is a way to achieve this with Azure data factory.
Someone  could help me on that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) from data factory.

Since there are multiple tables you want to load up, you need to build a for loop. Each table you need to loop is one iteration in this for loop:

[image]

Inside the copy activity, there's one more challenge to handle. You can't load the full tables content each iteration.
To load only the latest data, that haven't been loaded earlier, you need to implement some delta-load-mechanism.
These delta-load-mechanism are called CDC (change data capture) and act like a watermark. For CDC, there are different variants available and i recommend you the `query-based-cdc` for this usecase. More info here: https://www.qlik.com/us/change-data-capture/cdc-change-data-capture

The query based CDC data consumption in data factory could look like this:

```
SELECT * from dbo.table1 WHERE TIMESTAMP > GETDATE() -1
```